# conditional expectation of squared standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, proof-verification, conditional-probability

Let $A,B$ independent standard normals. What is $E(A^2|A+B)$?

Is the following ok?

$A,B$ iid and hence $(A^2,A+B),(B^2,A+B)$ iid.
Therefore we have $\int_M A^2 dP = \int_M B^2 dP$ for every $A+B$-measurable set $M$ and hence $E(A^2|A+B) = E(B^2|A+B)$.

We obtain $2 \cdot E(A^2|A+B) = E(A^2|A+B) + E(B^2|A+B) = E(A^2+B^2|A+B) = A^2+B^2$ where the last equation holds since $A^2+B^2$ is $A+B$-measurable.

Finally we have $E(A^2|A+B) = \frac{A^2+B^2}{2}$.

Comment: use that A, A+B are joint normal.  Find the conditional distribution of A given A+B

Comment: Doesn't a square normal have a chi-square distribution?

Comment: @user99680: Well, I do not know about that. But if I do not find a mistake in my line of argument it should hold that $E(A^2|A+B)=\frac{A^2+B^2}{2}$...can someone verify or disprove this result. (I checked the internet for chi-squared stuff which seems related, but we do not know about chi-squared distributions and for the above argument I would not need it.)

Comment: @flawspotter: Sorry, just thought it might help you double-check the result by using this to calculate the expected value.

Comment: @user99680: That might be a good idea but I do not know about chi-squared yet, hence can not really use this way of calculating the expected value...anyone who can verify my result or spots a mistake in my argument?

Comment: @flawspotter: It looks O.K to me, but maybe you also want to post it at stats stack : http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1) $A$ and $B$ are random variables, they can not appear in your answer for the expectation value. Instead you should use $\mu_A$,$\mu_B$,$\sigma_A$,$\sigma_B$. If you write your result as $E(A^2|A+B)=(1/2)E(A^2+B^2|A+B)$, it is valid. But $E(A^2|A+B)=(A^2+B^2)/2$ is not a valid answer

Comment: $E(A|B)$ is a random variable as well, no?

Answer (score 0):

if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $A^2$ and $A+B$ are not independent because $A^2$ and $A$ are correlated.

Comment: Actually, since $Cov(A^2,A)=E[A^3]-E[A^2]E[A]$ and $A\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, it turns out that $A$ and $A^2$ are not correlated (though obviously not independent). So your argument might not work.